# Almacenar subconsulta en una variable (PHP)

Tags: php, sql

Puedo almacenar en una variable el resultado de una consulta y usar el valor en otra consulta?

```
//consulta que quiero hacer primero
$consulta_pre_has = "SELECT
                         MAX(Prod_Pres) 
                     FROM productos";

//hago la consulta
$pre_has=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_pre_has);
```

Uso la variable $pre_has que en teoría almacena el valor de la consulta en otra consulta

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    productos 
WHERE  
    Prod_Pres 
BETWEEN 
    0 AND '$pre_has'
```

El problema es que si quiero mostrar en pantalla el valor de $pre_has no me muestra nada y por lo tanto entiendo que a la hora de hacer la anterior consulta el valor de $pre_has es nulo y por eso no me funciona

Comment: Antes de escribir la pregunta tómate un tiempo en formularla y organizarla, dices que la consulta "almacena" sin embargo muestras un `SELECT`, un poco después dices que usas la variable en un código y sin embargo muestras una consulta SQL con dos variables de PHP incrustadas. Para poder ayudarte primero tenemos que tener la información mínima y necesaria pero sobre todo que ésta esté bien formulada.

Comment: Mi pregunta es: **¿por qué necesitas dos consultas?** ¿No puedes obtener lo que quieres en una sola? No hagas en dos viajes lo que puedes hacer en uno solo. Sólo dejo la interrogante... :) Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Estás almacenando algo que no es realmente el resultado de tu consulta, sino un objeto respuesta de MySQLi

En vez de:

```
$consulta_pre_has = "SELECT MAX(Prod_Pres) FROM productos";  

$pre_has = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_pre_has);
```

Debiera ser:

```
$consulta_pre_has = "SELECT MAX(Prod_Pres) as pre_has FROM productos";  
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_pre_has);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$pre_has = $row['pre_has'];
```